# What is the relationship among Rikulo UI, Rikulo Gap and Bootjack?

Tags: dart, rikulo, bootjack

Can I use them separately? Can I use them with other solutions such as polymer?

Answer (score 1):

First, they are independent of each others. You can use them separately or together.

[Rikulo UI](http://rikulo.org/projects/ui) is a UI framework providing structured UI model that are 100% controllable in Dart. While it gives the Dart developers better control of UI and layout, it is designed more for mobile and desktop-look applications (than website-look).

[Bootjack](http://blog.rikulo.org/posts/2013/May/General/bootjack-and-dquery/) is a porting of Bootstrap in Dart. While Bootstrap is famous for its lightweight JS and the magic use of HTML5/CSS3, Bootjack is aimed for website-look applications and developers that prefer to design UI with less Dart code.

[Rikulo Gap](http://docs.rikulo.org/ui/latest/Rikulo_Gap/Fundamentals.html) is a bridge to [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) for building native mobile applications in Dart. It doesn't assume anything about UI, so you can use it with any UI frameworks you'd like, including Polymer and Angular.

Comment: To use several UI frameworks, such as Polymer and Bootjack, in one application, you usually need to take care of life cycle issues.